# Animals sixth sense

Tags: sources-mekorot, animals, science

It seems that there is evidence that animals possess a sixth sense, such as in their [fleeing](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2005/01/0104_050104_tsunami_animals.html) from the area struck by the huge tsunami of 2005 well before the earthquake which triggered it occurred. Is there a Jewish source supporting this? (I'm looking for something which also explains this, if it's possible to find such.)

Comment: Is there a Jewish source for animals (or people) having exactly 5?

Comment: As an aside I'd point out that Aristotle's "5 senses" is just something he came up with. People actually have many senses (sense of orientation, temperature, pressure, hunger, and so on). Different animals have other senses as well (sharks can sense electronic fields made by fish, bats can use echolocation, dolphins can use ultrasound to see through matter, some birds can sense magnetic orientation, etc.). Some animals being sensitive to small tremors wouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebbi Yirmiyah extrapolates from the Pasuk "va'Yeshalach es ha'Yonah me'Ito" that Tahor birds dwell with the Tzadikim - from the use of the word "me'Ito" (which the Torah does not use in connection with the raven). What he means is - that Tahor birds recognize a Tzadik when they see one (see also Agados Maharsha).  from http://dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/reviewa/sn-ra-108.htm

also seems from this http://www.torah.org/learning/ravfrand/5770/shoftim.html?print=1 that animals know the Gezeros (heavenly decrees):
"The Medrash teaches that the wise king knew the language of the birds (sichas haTziparim). A person came to Shlomo HaMelech and asked that Shlomo HaMelech teach him this language. At first, the king refused but the man pestered him until he finally relented and taught him sichas haTziparim (language of the birds). The fellow was then walking in the field and heard two birds talking with one another. One bird told the other "You see this fellow; his entire flock of cattle are going to die within the next couple of weeks." The man went home and immediately sold his entire flock of cattle at the very first opportunity. Lo and behold, two weeks later the entire flock died. The man avoided a major financial setback! "

Comment: Isn't that a mekach taut?

Comment: @DoubleAA, ask Rabbi Frand, or whatever _midrash_ he was quoting. This answer has no [problem](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) AFAICT.

Comment: @DoubleAA There are many sources for the fact that we don't _pasken_ or sue for money based on ESP-derived information, so I assume it is not.

Answer (score 9):

[Bamidbar 22:23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=302) mentions how Bilam's donkey saw an angel which Bilam could not see. [Rashi ad loc.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=303) implies that this was not a unique case: there are at times things that an animal can perceive which a human can not.

Comment: That animal could also talk ...

Comment: @IsaacMoses: but Rashi there says that "Hashem gave animals the ability to see what humans can't, because a person, who has intelligence, would become mentally deranged from seeing such destructive beings." So it's not just a quality of that particular donkey.

Comment: @Alex, Good point. Probably worth [edit]ing into the answer.

Comment: this does not explain whether animals know the gezeros such as the tsunami. but it does demonstrate that sometimes they can see things we can't.

Answer (score 3):

The Talmud ([Bava Kama 60b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=60b&format=pdf)) says the following:

> ת"ר כלבים בוכים מלאך המות בא לעיר כלבים משחקים אליהו הנביא בא לעיר וה"מ דלית בהו נקבה

Soncino Translation:

> Our Rabbis taught: When dogs howl, [this is a sign that] the Angel of Death has come to a town.
>   But when dogs frolic, [this is a sign that] Elijah the prophet has come to a town. This is so, however,
>   only if there is no female among them.